# Python Excel number of times a negative and positive number appears (count/frequency)

Tags: python, excel, count, frequency

I would like python to count the number of time a negative and positive number appears in binary [1 positive and 0 negative]. Furthermore, I would like Python to compute a percentage of how many positive numbers exist from the total count. I am having a very hard time figure this out when working with Python Excel.

This is the code that I have right now:

```
import csv

with open('Weather30states.csv', 'r') as file1:
     val = list(csv.reader(file1))[2]
     val1 = val[0:4]

with open('FL%.csv', 'r') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2)
    reader.next() # this skips the first row of the file
    # this iteration will start from the second row of file2.csv
    conditionMet = False
    for row in reader:
        if conditionMet == True:
            print "FA,",row[0],',', ','.join(row[1:5])
            conditionMet = False # or break if you know you only need at most one line
        if row[1:5] == val1:
           conditionMet = True
```

When I run this code, what I get in the output window is this:

```
FA, -1.97% , 0,0,1,0
FA, -0.07% , 0,0,1,1
FA, 0.45% , 0,1,1,1
FA, -0.07% , 0,0,1,1
FA, -0.28% , 0,0,1,1
```

What I want to get is this:

```
1, 0, FA, -1.97% , 0,0,1,0
2, 0, FA, -0.07% , 0,0,1,1
3, 1, FA, 0.45% , 0,1,1,1
4, 0, FA, -0.07% , 0,0,1,1
5, 0, FA, -0.28% , 0,0,1,1

Total Count = 5
Percentage of Positive numbers = .20 %
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample input for each file? It is not trivial to reverse engineer your input format to generate test output.

Comment: http://expirebox.com/download/9e946609d539e44052a5746e612e4ff8.html

Comment: http://expirebox.com/download/b08e2d316b0f6e14a822392650387b9f.html

Comment: I have added both of the files for you here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two counter variables to track of the total count and number of positives. Set them to 0 in the beginning, and then inside of your loop, increment them by using `+= 1` whenever you want to add 1.

Then test whether the percentage is greater than 0 by stripping out the percentage sign and then converting the string into a number using `if float(row[0].strip('%')) > 0`. You can change this to `>=` if you want to include 0 in the "positive" category.

```
totalCount = 0
numberOfPositives = 0

with open('FL%.csv', 'r') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file2)
    reader.next() # this skips the first row of the file
    # this iteration will start from the second row of file2.csv
    conditionMet = False
    for row in reader:
        if conditionMet == True:
            if float(row[0].strip('%')) > 0: # change > to >= if you want to count 0 as positive
                print "FA, 1",row[0],',', ','.join(row[1:5]) # print 1 if positive
                numberOfPositives += 1 # add 1 to numberOfPositives only if positive
            else:
                print "FA, 0",row[0],',', ','.join(row[1:5]) # print 0 if not positive
            totalCount += 1 # add 1 to totalCount regardless of sign
            conditionMet = False # or break if you know you only need at most one line
        if row[1:5] == val1:
           conditionMet = True
```

Then you can calculate the sum and percentage you need from `totalCount` and `numberOfPositives`:

```
print 'Total Count =', totalCount
print 'Percentage of Positive numbers =', numberOfPositives * 100./totalCount, '%'
```

Comment: I tried this it does not work. When I run the code nothing happens. Furthermore I think the last part you wrote print 'Percentage of Positive numbers =', numOfPositives * 100./totalCount, '%' should be changed to numberOfPostivies right???

Comment: I've corrected my answer in two ways: first, to parse the percentages from your example file, and second, to fix the typing error you pointed out. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much. this has been stressing me out for a week now. Thank you again :)

Comment: No problem, hopefully you can look over it and learn the concepts so that you can apply them yourself next time. The concepts are much more powerful than the implementation. :)

Comment: True :) I am still not that comfortable with loops. But this helps me understand it a lot better now thank you again :)